# Ionic social login with WordPress backend JSON API User

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to build an Ionic application with  WordPress back-end.
I Installed JSON API user,and I want to use Facebook login, but I can not figure it out how I will call the token and pass it to the JSON page. Please any recommend any good article about these technologies, it will help a lot.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy, once you have configured Facebook.
You must have FB plugin
installed. Once you call facebook cordova plugin you will get token in response after you try to call fb.login.
And then you can call fb connect function and pass access_token

```
getWPToken(facebooktoken){
       this.http.get('yourdomaindotcom/json-api/user/fb_connect/?
     access_token='+token).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
     console.log(data);
     this.cookie = data.cookie;

    this.storage.get('wp_cookie').then((val)=>{

      this.storage.set("wp_cookie", this.cookie);
      this.event.publish("cookie",this.cookie);


    });

  },
  err => {
    console.log("Oops!");
  });

}
```